# a link to server could not be established

Tags: php

i write this code in Database class ...

```
public function DeleteArticle($list)
   {
       $this->setdata("DELETE FROM Article WHERE Code IN (" . implode(',', $list) . ")");
   }
 private function connect()
   {
      mysql_connect('localhost' ,'#######' ,'########' );
      mysql_select_db('allatala_db');
   }
  public function setdata($query)
   {
       $this->connect();
       mysql_query($query);
       mysql_close();
   }
```

and call it in my adminpage.php

```
if(isset($_POST['delete1']))
   {
            $obj=new Database();  
        $obj->DeleteArticle($_POST['checkbox']);

   }
```

so...  in my localhost server work it properly but in the server i have this problem 
a link to server could not be established

Help me plz

Comment: Do you have any errors in the error log? Most probably, it is unable to connect to mysql and freezes.

Comment: yes this error message Access Denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password :no )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code has no error so there is some minor mistake.
Just make sure of following things.

1) Your server is running, Also try to open phpmyadmin in browser.
2) Open phpmyadmin and check your username and password under utilities.
3) User which you have created must have rights which is needed.

I think your problem would be solve after checking this things.

Comment: i have not problem in phpmyadmin but when i try to delete record in remote server i got error

Comment: It may possible you have created user and that user don't have rights of DELETE

Comment: Then print your delete query before you execute. there might be some problem with implode.